# How does JikesRVM work without third-party JVM support?

Tags: java, jvm, runtime

I am new to JikesRVM. I get confused at first that how the RVM run by itself without a third-party VM support, given that the RVM is implemented by Java language.

Now I understand that the JikesRVM has a boot image runner which would load the data, code and rmap images into memory before passing control the the RVM. How do the images look like? It looks like they are machine code that can be directly executed. But what compiler generates the images, directly from Java language to machine code?

Thanks a lot in advance for any inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://jikesrvm.org/Building+the+RVM), the bootstrap is written in C and compiled in GCC

Comment: What about the RVM implementation code written in Java? Are they complied to native code (and built as images) that can directly execute?

Comment: @user2611914 They're compiled to bytecode and executed by the bootstrap

Comment: @user2611914 If you're looking for a way to compile Java to native code then you may want to look at [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/), though it only supports up to Java 1.4, most ahead-of-time compilers that I'm aware of require a commercial license

Comment: I did some more research and it looks like the RVM Java code methods have already been compiled to native machine code (which are stored in the one of the images: RVM.code.image) by the boot image writer (who has a compiler in it), although the RVM java objects are still maintained as object in JikesRVM object model. That is to say, no bytecode-native translation occurs at runtime. After boot image runner loads the boot images into memory and configuring environment, the RVM is ready to go. Let me know if I am wrong. (Reference: The Jalapen ̃o virtual machine, B. Alpern)

Comment: @user2611914 I wouldn't trust that source, as it dates back to 2000 - Java ahead-of-time compilation was more of an active research topic back then since Java's just-in-time compiler wasn't very good, but now the just-in-time compiler is good enough that java-to-native compilers are typically only used for [real-time Java](http://www.rtsj.org/)